# Join two, three related tables by HQL

Tags: java, mysql, hql

I have three related tables like below:

```
+-------------+---------+------------+
| customer_id | name    | surname    |
+-------------+---------+------------+
|           1 | Jan     | Bielecki   |
|           2 | Adam    | Bielen     |
.....

+----------+--------+---------------------+-------------+
| order_id | amount | date                | customer_id |
+----------+--------+---------------------+-------------+
|        1 |  10.23 | 2017-02-15 00:00:00 |           1 |
|        2 |  20.56 | 2017-02-16 00:00:00 |           1 |
|        3 |  30.57 | 2017-02-17 00:00:00 |           2 |
|        4 |  40.52 | 2017-02-18 00:00:00 |           2 |
|        5 |  50.30 | 2017-02-19 00:00:00 |           1 |
.....

+-----------------+-----------+------------+----------+
| order_detail_id | item_name | item_price | order_id |
+-----------------+-----------+------------+----------+
|               1 | item 1    |       2.00 |        1 |
|               2 | item 2    |       2.50 |        1 |
|               3 | item 3    |       3.00 |        1 |
|               4 | item 4    |       4.00 |        2 |
|               5 | item 5    |       5.50 |        2 |
|               6 | item 6    |       7.60 |        3 |
|               7 | item 7    |       5.00 |        3 |
|               8 | item 8    |       3.00 |        4 |
|               9 | item 9    |       7.00 |        4 |
|              10 | item 10   |       8.00 |        4 |
|              11 | item 11   |       2.00 |        5 |
|              12 | item 12   |       2.50 |        5 |
.....
```

Firstly i'm fighting with connect first and second table. For connect surnames with sum of amount.

I'm trying like this:

```
select sum(o.amount) as totalSum
from Order as o,
Customer as c
join c.surname as surname
where c.orders:=o.customer
group by o.customer
order by sum(o.amount) desc
```

with changing to many ways this section: `where c.orders:=o.customer`
The most common error is NullPointerException.

Before done this in SQL:
Table customer_id <-> total_amount

```
SELECT customer_id,
SUM(amount) as total_amount,
COUNT(amount) as orders_quantity
FROM softhis_db.orders
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Table customer_id <-> 3 most exp. orders + dates

```
SELECT orders.customer_id, orders.amount, orders.date
FROM orders_details
RIGHT JOIN orders
ON orders.order_id = orders_details.order_id
ORDER BY amount DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Customer:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer {

@Id
@Column(name = "customer_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", length = 50)
private String name;

@Column(name = "surname", length = 50)
private String surname;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();
```

Order:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

@Id
@Column(name = "order_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "date")
private Date date;

@Digits(integer = 5, fraction = 2)
@Column(name = "amount")
private BigDecimal amount;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
private Customer customer;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
private Set<OrderDetail> ordersDetails = new HashSet<>();
```

OrderDetail:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders_details")
public class OrderDetail {

@Id
@Column(name = "order_detail_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Lon id;

@Column(name = "item_name", length = 50)
private String itemName;

@Digits(integer = 5, fraction = 2)
@Column(name = "item_price")
private BigDecimal itemPrice;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
private Order order;
```

The point is how to do this properly in HQL ? Next step will be searching by surname and getting result like 'my target'.

My target is:

```
+---------+---------------+
| surname | sum of amount | 
+---------+---------------+
|Bielecki | 150.40        | 
|Bielen   | 130.34        |
......

+-----------------------------------+--------------------+
| surname | 3 most expensive orders | date               |
+-----------------------------------+--------------------+
|Bielecki | 120.23                  |2017-02-15 00:00:00 | 
|Bielecki | 80.20                   |2017-02-18 00:00:00 |
|Bielecki | 20.20                   |2017-02-19 00:00:00 |
+---------+-------------------------+--------------------+
|Bielen   | 190.23                  |2017-02-15 00:00:00 | 
|Bielen   | 80.20                   |2017-02-18 00:00:00 |
|Bielen   | 20.20                   |2017-02-19 00:00:00 |
+---------+-------------------------+--------------------+
.....
```

Comment: Please elaborate your target output

Comment: @RaymondNijland what do you mean ?

Comment: show us the expected output based on the example data not only column headers

Comment: @RaymondNijland see updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to translate those SQL queries to HQL.
In order:

1.

```
select o.customer.surname, sum(o.amount) as s from Order as o group by o.customer
```

2.

```
select o.customer.surname, o.amount, o.date from Order as o, OrderDetail as od
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these queries

```
SELECT
   customers.surname
 , SUM(amount) "sum of amount"
FROM 
 customers
INNER JOIN
 orders 
ON
  customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
GROUP BY
  customers.surname
ORDER BY
 customers.surname ASC
```

For the 3 most expensive orders per surname you need to use user variables to create ranking. 
And filter on that ranking.

```
SELECT
   customers.surname
 , orders_ranked.amount AS "3 most expensive orders"
 , orders_ranked.date
FROM ( 
  SELECT 
   *
   , (
     CASE
         WHEN
           @customer_id = orders.customer_id
         THEN
           @rank := @rank + 1 
         ELSE
           @rank := 1 
       END
     )
     AS
       rank
    , @customer_id := orders.customer_id     
  FROM 
   orders
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 
        @customer_id := 0
      , @rank := 0
    )
     AS
       init_user_variables 
   ORDER BY 
     orders.customer_id ASC
   , orders.amount DESC 
 ) 
  AS 
    orders_ranked
INNER JOIN 
 customers
ON
 orders_ranked.customer_id = customers.customer_id    
WHERE 
   orders_ranked.rank <= 3
```

Comment: Thank you @RaymondNijland it's working but i need the same in HQL

Comment: @twistezo iam not known with HQL.. but i think you can use `session.createSQLQuery(query).list()` for this read https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html